# Proof that combined matrices are idempotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Suppose that $X_{nxp} (n>p)$ is a matrix such that $X'X$  is invertible.

- Prove that both $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and $I_n-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$  are idempotent.
- Prove that the tr $X(X'X)^{-1}X' =p$  and tr $(I_n - X(X'X)^{-1}X')=n-p$.

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I am still trying to figure this out but I believe it is related to property of matrix multiplication: (AB)C=A(BC).

Comment: The first part should be really straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$(X(X'X)^{-1}X')^2 = (X(X'X)^{-1}X')(X(X'X)^{-1}X') = X(X'X)^{-1}(X'X)(X'X)^{-1}X'=X(X'X)^{-1}X', \tag 1$

which shows that $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is idempotent.  Now note that for any idempotent $P$,

$P^2 = P, \tag 2$

we have

$(I - P)^2 = I - 2P + P^2 = I - 2P + P = I - P \tag 3$

is also idempotent; applying this fact to $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ shows that $I_n - X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is idempotent as well.

We compute the trace of $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ as follows:  in [the wikipedia article on traces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)), it is shown that
for $A$ and $n \times m$ matrix and $B$ and $m \times n$ matrix,

$\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA); \tag 4$

applying this to $X(X'X)^{-1}$ and $X'$ yields

$\text{tr}((X(X'X)^{-1})X') = \text{tr}(X'(X(X'X)^{-1}))$
$= \text{tr}((X'X)(X'X)^{-1}) = \text{tr}(I_p) = p, \tag 5$

where $I_p$ is the $p \times p$ identity matrix. Then

$\text{tr}(I_n - X(X'X)^{-1})X') = \text{tr}(I_n) - \text{tr}(I_p) = n - p. \tag 6$

Comment: I am really grateful for your precious input. Sorry my reputation is  below 15 so I could not upvote you now but I promise that I will do once I reach that. Please let me know your input about the second half of the 1st question.

Comment: @MohamedRahouma:  I'm not sure what you mean exactly-- I thought I answered that.  I proved they are both idempotent *ca.* (1)-(3).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful answer. Greatly appreciated. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Let us put
$$ A \colon= X \left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^\prime. $$
Then we note that
$$
\begin{align}
A^2 &= AA \\
&= \left[ X \left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^\prime \right] \left[ X \left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^\prime  \right] \\
&= X \left[ \left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1}  \left( X^\prime X \right) \right] \left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^\prime  \\
&= X I_{p\times p} \left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^\prime \\
&= X \left(X^\prime X\right)^{-1} X^\prime \\
&= A.
\end{align}
$$

Now let us put 
$$ B \colon= I_n-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T. $$
Then we find that 
$$
\begin{align}
B^2 &= BB \\
&=  \left[ I_n-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \right] \left[ I_n-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \right] \\
&= I_n \left[ I_n- X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \right] - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \left[ I_n-X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \right] \\
&= I_n I_n - I_n X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T I_n + \left[ X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \right] \left[ X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \right] \\
&= I_n -  X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T + X\left[ (X^TX)^{-1} \left( X^T X\right) \right] \left[ (X^TX)^{-1}X^T \right] \\
&= I_n - 2 X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T   + X I_n \left[ (X^TX)^{-1} X^T \right] \\
&= I_n - 2 X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T   + X \left[ (X^TX)^{-1} X^T  \right] \\
&= I_n - 2 X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T   + X (X^TX)^{-1} X^T   \\
&= I_n -  X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \\
&= B. 
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious input. Sorry my reputation is less than 15 so I could not upvote you now but I will do later once I reach that. Please let me know your input about the second half of the 1st point of my questions.

Comment: @MohamedRahouma  please have a look at my post now. I've included the stuff you've asked for.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts. I do not completely understand line 3-5. If you kindly could refer to the original formula as in number (4) in Robert's answer, that will be really more helpful to understand as I am still struggling to get your steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful answer. Greatly appreciated. Upvoted.